# Stack rasters with different origin, dimensions and resolution in R

Tags: raster, r, resolution, stack, dimensions

I have three raster files with the same extent and CRS, but with different origin, dimensions and resolution.

```
r1
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 3020, 3043, 9189860  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.003446425, 0.003657477  (x, y)
extent      : -8.69165, 1.79582, 49.83774, 60.88332  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : r1
values      : -0.272593, 5616  (min, max)

r2
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 1221, 655, 799755  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.0160114, 0.009046339  (x, y)
extent      : -8.69165, 1.79582, 49.83774, 60.88332  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : r2
values      : 0, 10  (min, max)

r3
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 1326, 1259, 1669434  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.00833, 0.00833  (x, y)
extent      : -8.69165, 1.79582, 49.83774, 60.88332  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : r3
values      : -0.4956901, 8.6887  (min, max)
```

When I try to create a raster stack, I get the following error:

```
predictors<-stack(r1, r2, r3)
Error in compareRaster(x) : different number or columns
```

I tried to re-sample r1,r2 according to one raster, lets say r3 - but it did not work.

Any advice how to solve this issue?

The rasters can be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zfbm05qwmsgp0lh/AAC7xGxSUuEyYeIQbqSqh1FPa?dl=0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `projectRaster()` to resample to a new resolution (also extent and CRS):

```
r2resampled <- projectRaster(r2,r1,method = 'ngb')
r3resampled <- projectRaster(r3,r1,method = 'bilinear')
```

The first one is categorical, so it's necessary to use nearest neighbor as method (`ngb`). The second one is numeric, so you can use bilinear (`bilinear`) or nearest neighbor (some researchers prefer to use `ngb` as method because with bilinear you are changing the original information to the new resolution, especially in RS products).

Check the result:

```
plot(stack(r1,r2resampled,r3resampled))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For unifying dimensions and resolutions of rasters, `resample()` function from `Raster` package works well for me:

```
library(raster)

r1 <- raster("Animal.tif")
r2 <- raster("LandTrans.tif")
r3 <- raster("TempJan.tif")

r1 <- resample(r1,r3)
r2 <- resample(r2,r3,method='ngb')

rs <- stack(r1,r2,r3)

plot(rs)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is not necessary to create new dataset. R is able to work with vrt files thanks to a [wrapper](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gdalUtils/versions/2.0.1.7/topics/gdalbuildvrt), so you can use virtual raster files as input. Just make shure that you set the **separate** option to true. You can also select the resampling method using the **r** parameter.